# Ampscript Lookup function on field which is null

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using this function:

```
%%=Lookup("ENT.SBQQ__QuoteLine__c_Salesforce","SBQQ__ProductName__c","sbqq__quote__c", "a0n5E000002KZHQQA4", "SBQQ__Required", @required)=%%
```

which works all the times (it returns the proper value) except when @required is null (it should return a string in such case as well).

I tried with  `@required = ''` or  `@required = null` but with no luck.

How can I solve it?

My goal is to get SBQQ__ProductName__c where sbqq__quote__c is a0n5E000002KZHQQA4 AND where SBQQ__Required is null.

thank you

Comment: What field type is SBQQ__Required?

Comment: SBQQ__Required  is a text

Comment: not even = "null" is working

Comment: @eeadev Did you tried empty function %%=Empty(@required )=%% ? I believe this should work.

Comment: Yes @eeadev is right, empty will return true if required = ""

Comment: I was not clear enough, my goal is to get SBQQ__ProductName__c where sbqq__quote__c is a0n5E000002KZHQQA4 AND where SBQQ__Required is null

Answer (score 0):

@required attribute needs have a value. You would need to handle the logic if its empty. 
So, if the @required is empty then set a different value.
@required value should be in the lookup data extension.

See the below code:

```
%%[
Set @required = AttributeValue("SBQQ__Required") 
If Empty(@required) THEN
Set @required = "NULL"
set @result = Lookup("ENT.SBQQ__QuoteLine__c_Salesforce","SBQQ__ProductName__c","sbqq__quote__c", "a0n5E000002KZHQQA4", "SBQQ__Required", @required)
Else
set @result = Lookup("ENT.SBQQ__QuoteLine__c_Salesforce","SBQQ__ProductName__c","sbqq__quote__c", "a0n5E000002KZHQQA4", "SBQQ__Required",@required) 
ENDIF
]%%
SBQQ__ProductName__c - %%=v(@result)=%%
```

Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Thanks for your time @razor, unfortunately it does not work. if u set required to "NULL", in my opinion ampscript set the value to the string "NULL" and when it search doing a lookup it returns no value because there is no such entry having the "NULL"

Comment: @eeadev yes that's correct. You need a value 'NULL' in the look up data extension instead of blank. Then the value will populate. In short, you need to have a value for the field to look up. If you don't have a value then it wont return anything.

Comment: I edited my initial message to make it clearer